# Existence of a limit of alpha-difference quotient for Hölder functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, fractional-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^d,d\geq 1,$ be an Hölder function with exponent $\alpha\in (0,1)$, meaning that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x, y \in \mathbb R, \,x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}<\infty.
\end{equation}
Define a set
\begin{equation}
A_f:=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}: u_f(x)>l_f(x)\right\},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
u_f(x):=\limsup_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha},\quad l_f(x):=\liminf_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}.
\end{equation}
The set $A_f$ is the set of all points $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where the limit $\lim_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}$ does not exist.

Does there exist an Hölder function $f$ with exponent
$\alpha\in (0,1)$ as above such that
$$
\mathcal{L}^1(A_f)>0\; ?$$
Here $\mathcal{L}^1$ is the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

**Remark:**
If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is differentiable almost everywhere, then at each differentiable point
$x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to x_0}\frac{|f(x_0)-f(y)|}{|x_0-y|^\alpha}=\lim_{y\to x_0}\frac{|f(x_0)-f(y)|}{|x_0-y|}|x_0-y|^{1-\alpha}=0.
\end{equation}
Hence, $\mathcal{L}^1(A_f)=0$. So if there exists an Hölder function as above, then it has to be non-differentiable on a set of positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Denote by $C(f)$ the first supremum in your question. If I remember correctly, the functions for which at _every_ point $u_f=C$ and $\liminf_{y\to x} (f(x)-f(y))/|x-y|^\alpha=-C$ (without the modulus at the numerator) are residual (therefore dense) in the space of Holder functions with $C(f)\leq C$.

Comment: Hey Del, thank you for your response. I'm not familiar with the density property you have mentioned. Can you give some reference?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any reference, I just remember that it should be proved in a standard way, similar to the way you prove similar Baire-type results. I will try to recall it